# Intersection points of the major cycles of $S^3$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Which are the intersection points of the major cycles of $S^3$

$$x_1(\theta_1)=\cos{\theta_1} e_1 + \sin{\theta_1} e_2, x_2(\theta_2)=\sin{\theta_2} e_1 +\cos{\theta_2} e_3, \theta_1, \theta_2 \in [0,2 \pi)$$

?

So we want that $x_1(\theta_1)=x_2(\theta_2)$ ?

If so, I have thought the following:

Since $e_1$ appear at both $x_1, x_2$, it has to hold that $\cos{\theta_1}=\sin{\theta_2}$ and $\sin{\theta_1}=\cos{\theta_2}=0$ since $e_2$ appears only at $x_1$ and $e_3$ only at $x_2$.

We have that $cos^2 y+ \sin^2y=1$.

So $\sin^2{\theta_1}+\cos^2{\theta_1}=1 \Rightarrow \cos{\theta_1} \in \{ \pm 1 \}$.

$\sin^2{\theta_2}+\cos^2{\theta_2}=1 \Rightarrow \sin{\theta_2} \in \{ \pm 1\}$.

Does this help somehow? Or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes so $(1, 0, 0)$ at $\theta_1 = 0, 2\pi, \theta_2 = \pi/2$ is one solution. $(-1, 0, 0)$ at $\theta_1 = \pi, \theta_2 = 3\pi/2$ is another.

Comment: "...it has to hold" is OK because the set $\{e_1, e_2, e_3\}$ is linearly independent, so if $$(\cos\theta_1 - \sin\theta_2)e_1 + \sin\theta_1\, e_1 - \cos\theta_2\, e_3 = 0,$$ the coefficients all are $0$. Alternatively, look at the intersection of the $(e_1, e_2)$ and $(e_1, e_3)$-planes, then consider where this line intersects the sphere. (Tangentially, are you in $S^3$, the unit sphere in Euclidean four-space, or $S^2$, the unit sphere in three-space?)